# Manual opcode parsing

Tags: c++, sqlite

In the following snippet I am attempting to manually iterate through the sqlite3 virtual machine to investigate opcodes.

I though that `vdbe->nOp`  should return the number of operations for my query but it returns a number of operations that changes every time I run the code and seems wildly incorrect.  This particular query should only have 20 opcodes according to `.explain` in sqlite3.exe.  When I run the code below I see values for `nOp` in the millions, far larger than the size of `vdbe->aOp`.  Code segfaults.

```
void debug_query(){
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    sqlite3 *db;
    sqlite3_open("./data/dummy_data.db", &db);

    int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT * FROM track", 256, &stmt, NULL);
    if( rc!=SQLITE_OK ) {
        printf("query failed\n");
        return;
    }
    Vdbe *vdbe = (Vdbe*) stmt;
    VdbeOp *o = vdbe->aOp;
    std::cout << vdbe->nOp << std::endl;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < vdbe->nOp && o[i].opcode != OP_Next; i++);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your declaration of `Vdbe` and the one used in `sqlite` compilation are the same? (i.e. you don't use one version when sqlite uses newer or older).

Comment: @keltar Fairly sure.  sqlite 3.6.22 is compiled as part of the project.

Comment: Works for me. (adding `main` function right into latest sqlite3.c amalgamation). If it would work with standalone amalgamation - I assume your build flags not in sync.

Comment: @Keltar Thank you for the sanity check.  I opted to compile sqlite3.c directly in to my application instead linking to its shared lib.  Things are working as expected.